# Windows 7 shows Not connected even if I am connected to internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet-connection

Windows 7 shows Not connected (with a red cross)even if I am connected to internet. 
This problem continues all the time. I have one network adapter. I have tried disabling and then enabling the adapter, it fixes the problem for once. But when i connect the internet again, the problem continues again.
http://s7.postimage.org/v4xvh0fuh/Internet.jpg

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about the issue you're experiencing and how you expect us to help you with your problem.

Comment: If [this](http://i.imgur.com/0JEjP.png) is on your screen right now, then, yes, it's a simple issue and you provided enough details. If something else is on your screen, maybe your description doesn't do it justice.

Comment: It would help a lot if you actually provided details other than an adapter is not connected.  Is this only on start-up or all the time?  Does your computer have more than one network adapter?  What steps have you already taken to fix the problem?

Comment: If it were a simple issue, to you, you would have already Googled it and found out the answer. This makes me think it is not so simple to you.

Comment: @MBraedley This problem continues all the time. I have one network adapter. I have tried disabling and then enabling the adapter, it fixes the problem for once. But when i connect the internet again, the problem continues again.

Comment: @Shanky: Okay, this is a good start now, but it raises more questions, like how do you connect to the internet?  Try to think about what other questions might be asked based on the information you're providing, and answer them preemptively.  If you don't know the answer to those questions, say so.  I'm not trying to get on your case, as I've been guilty of not providing enough information before, but you'll find that you'll get faster and better answers if you provide more information up front.

Comment: @MBraedley I connect internet through a 3G Modem.

Comment: @MBraedley You'll get a clear view after seeing this image http://s7.postimage.org/v4xvh0fuh/Internet.jpg

Comment: you can check this out http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/. If www.msftncsi.com is not accessible for you, then Windows says internet is not available

Comment: @Shanky a network adapter and modem are not the same thing.  Go to your Network Settings, and then Network Connections.  Which connections/adapters are visible under there?  (It might be called "Change adapter settings" under the Network and Sharing Center).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 network cards: wired + wifi
You see the icon of the disconnected card. The connected one remain hidden.

Comment: I surely have 1 network card.